# Remove URL GET param for locale Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have different languages in my app and I am using this pattern: `/:locale/some-action`. Most of my routes are in this scope `:locale` - routes.rb:

```
scope "(:locale)", locale: /fr|en/ do
  root to: 'home#index'
  get 'contacts', to: 'contacts#index'
end
get 'about', to: 'about#index'
```

, but some of them are not. For routes which are in this scope `:locale`, if I use their names like `contacts_path`, Rails generates the route depends on the locale. If it is `:fr`, generated route will be `/fr/contacts`.

For routes which aren't in this scope. For the example `about`. If I use its name `about_path` and locale is `:fr`, the generated URL will be `/about?locale=fr`, but I don't want this.

This is `application_controller.rb`:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  before_action :set_locale

  private
  def set_locale
    I18n.locale = params[:locale] || I18n.default_locale
  end

  def default_url_options(options={})
    { :locale => I18n.locale == I18n.default_locale ? nil : I18n.locale  }
  end
end
```

What is the way to remove this GET parameter, but still using routes which are in scope `:locale` with their names and generated URLs depends on `:locale` ?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. In my views:

```
<%= link_to 'About', about_path(locale: nil) %>
```